# jQuery to check if element has no specific class applied

Tags: jquery

I would like to check if an element has not a specific class applied. Is this correct?

```
if($('#tabs_wrapper li').hasClass:not('enabled')){
$('.inner_tabs div').css('display', 'none');
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just an alternative

```
if ($('#tabs_wrapper li:not(".enabled")').length) {
   /* ... */
}
```

Comment: this worked for me thank you $('li:not(".enabled") .inner_tabs div').css('display', 'none');

Comment: Alex, `$('li', '#tabs_wrapper').not(".enabled").find('.inner_tabs div').css('display', 'none');` takes account of `#tabs_wrapper` and will, for other reasons, be more efficient despite being more verbose.

Answer (score 1):

You may do this :

```
 if (!$('#tabs_wrapper li').is('.enabled')){
    $('.inner_tabs div').css('display', 'none');
 }
```

[Reference](http://api.jquery.com/is/)